# Visual Studio 2012 not compiling anymore after changes made

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i recently installed VS 12 Service Pack 1.
Since then, i noticed Visual Studio doesn't compile my project on start if changes were made.

Normally if you start (debugging) a project which has some changes, it recompiles it and starts then. But now, i always get debugging errors like "this breakpoint can´t be reached, because the source code is unequal to the runtime code" or whatever.

It´s annoying to recompile it manually always before starting - I always forget that :-/

Is there any option to fix this?

Comment: I´m using C#, if that is what you meant ;)

Comment: Make sure the project is checked in the solution configuration properties.

Comment: All projects are checked, of course. That´s not the problem...

Comment: Do the projects have dependencies known to Visual Studio (a project reference) or do you reference by choosing a DLL from disk? Which project is set as the Startup project? It should be the one that references others (in contrast to one without references and a "start external program" setting).

Answer (score 3):

Can you check if the build on run option is set?

You will find it under Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Build and Run.

I dont have a good answer as to why this would have been flipped just via installing the update1.

Comment: It´s set to "Always build". I did this as it was the only thing i knew that it could cause this problem ... But nothing changed :-/

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should enter the Solution's Property Pages (by right clicking the solution in the Solution Explorer pane) and setting the 'build' check-box of the relevant project.

Comment: Thanks, but I already checked that and this was not the issue. Anyway meanwhile this has fixed itself, probably by reinstalling / upgrading Visual Studio.